# How do we change the size of a JavaFX Canvas because of a change of local values?

Tags: canvas, javafx, resize

There are excellent solutions on stackOverflow to change the size of a JavaFX Canvas due to the user resizing the window. But how does one change the size of a Canvas because of input changes on the canvas that result in changing variables and redrawing, NOT by the user resizing?

Does this require binding not to a surrounding window, but perhaps to some field in the Canvas class? One excellent tip says to do the 5 steps shown below. But I don't know how to change step 5 to bind width property to a field of the class --the one that will change.

1. Create a subclass of Canvas.
2. Override the isResizable() method and return true.
3. Override the prefWidth() and prefHeight() methods. Return the values of Canvas.getWidth() and Canvas.getHeight().
4. Add listeners to the width and height properties of Canvas in order to trigger a redraw when the size of the canvas changes.
5. Bind the width and height properties of Canvas to the width and height properties of the parent pane.

Comment: By "input changes" do you mean as a result of the user doing something? You would typically do this by means of an event handler.

Comment: Yes, but  am at a loss how to do it. Please see my edited question above.

Comment: I just found another way to do it, which appears to work in situation: remove the current Canvas and create another one. Much easier.